# How can I extract information from HTML depending on the structure

Tags: java, parsing

I want to extract some data from many links from xbox. The problem I am experiencing is that in the section where the price is shown, the structure is different if the game is with discount (for example).

The code I have written to scrap the price:

```
String urlPage = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare-gold-edition/c20hl06x0v8w" ;
        System.out.println("Comprobando entradas de: "+urlPage);

        if (getStatusConnectionCode(urlPage) == 200) {

            Document document = getHtmlDocument(urlPage);

            Elements entradas = document.select("div.m-product-detail-hero-product-placement div.price-info");

            for (Element elem : entradas) {
                String titulo = elem.getElementsByClass("srv_saleprice").text();
                }


        }else{
            System.out.println("El Status Code no es OK es: "+getStatusConnectionCode(urlPage));
        }
```

The HTML for a game that has no discount:

[URL for first case](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare-gold-edition/c20hl06x0v8w)

```html
<div class="price-info"> 
 <div class="c-price"> 
  <div class="price-text srv_price"> 
   <div class="ea-vault-message hidden x-hidden"> 
    <div>
     Available in The Vault
    </div> 
    <div>
     or
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <span>$59.99</span> 
   <sup>+</sup> 
  </div> 
  <div class="srv_microdata" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"> 
   <meta itemprop="price" content="59.99"> 
   <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

And for a game with discount:

[URL for the second case](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/grand-theft-auto-v-megalodon-shark-cash-card-bundle/c54tnmrcbh0c)

```html
<div class="price-info"> 
 <div class="c-price"> 
  <div class="price-text srv_price"> 
   <div class="ea-vault-message hidden x-hidden"> 
    <div>
     Available in The Vault
    </div> 
    <div>
     or
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <s class="srv_saleprice" aria-label="Full price was $159.99">$159.99</s> 
   <span>&nbsp;</span> 
   <div class="price-disclaimer"> 
    <span>$135.99</span> 
    <sup>+</sup> 
   </div> 
   <span>&nbsp;</span> 
   <span></span> 
  </div> 
  <div class="caption text-muted srv_countdown"> 
   <span class="sub">save $24.00</span> 
  </div> 
  <div class="srv_microdata" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"> 
   <meta itemprop="price" content="135.99"> 
   <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

In this second example the value inside  elements is $135.99 but is not the game base price ($159.99 in this case).

How could I extract only the base price for every game (with or without) discount?

Comment: I'd have a look at [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/), which has the ability to query the html and perform various lookups, this way you could check the structure for the required information, if it doesn't exist, you could check it using an alternative query...

Comment: If the page does not have a `class="srv_saleprice"` element, why not find the `class="srv_microdata"` element and read the price and currency from its `<meta>` children?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using jSoup but I didn't know it has that option. Is there any example to look at?

Comment: @VGR But it happens the same, the content inside the meta is the ACTUAL price, not the base price. In the first example the base value is 59.99 and in the second one is 159.99, so if I extract the content of that meta element I will be doing the same. The only solution I have thought about is to make conditionals but it's going to make the code difficult to read.

Comment: @JetLagFox Maybe [Use selector-syntax to find elements](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)